# Minimal Matter.js example : Engine.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

I literally copied the code from the [getting started section](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Getting-started) of the Matter.js library but an **Uncaught TypeError occurs: "Engine.run is not a function"**.
I searched everywhere on the web but nothing helps. As a precaution, I added an event listener to run the code once everything is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.9.2/matter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Matter.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load",init);

        function init() {
            // module aliases
            var Engine = Matter.Engine,
                Render = Matter.Render,
                Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
                Composite = Matter.Composite;

            // create an engine
            var engine = Engine.create();

            // create a renderer
            var render = Render.create({
                element: document.body,
                engine: engine
            });

            // create two boxes and a ground
            var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
            var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
            var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

            // add all of the bodies to the world
            Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

            // run the engine
            Engine.run(engine);

            // run the renderer
            Render.run(render);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong version of matter-js library, try with latest version. I just tried with **0.15.0**, it's working fine.

matter-js >= `0.10.0` has the support `Render.run()`. Please make sure the version which you are using for supported features.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",init);

        function init() {
            // module aliases
            var Engine = Matter.Engine,
                Render = Matter.Render,
                Runner = Matter.Runner,
                Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
                Composite = Matter.Composite;

            // create an engine
            var engine = Engine.create();

            // create a renderer
            var render = Render.create({
                element: document.body,
                engine: engine
            });

            // create two boxes and a ground
            var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
            var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(450, 50, 80, 80);
            var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

            // add all of the bodies to the world
            Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

            // run the engine
            Runner.run(engine);

            // run the renderer
            Render.run(render);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.0/matter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Matter.js example</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with 0.15, but with the latest build (v0.17), the error still occurs, even though it's the version suggested by the getting started? wtf?

Comment: It does support in v0.17. check [Render.run](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/930311962966f70ff1fc08a2d0fb911f04880f7c/src/render/Render.js#L137). you might be getting different error.

Comment: @Tibère, now it's issue with `Engine.run`. as per their documentation, [Engine.run](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Engine.html#method_run) is an alias for `Runner.run'. It's strange, it did work with `Runner.run` but not with `Engine.run` :). updated code snippet with `Runner.run`.

Comment: I'm still a very bad investigator... thanks a lot!